# Several questions about <chrono> header in C++ 11

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, c++-chrono

I have several questions about new `<chrono>` header in C++ 11. Using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012.

Looking at the example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n < 3) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int result = fibonacci(42);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
                             (end-start).count();
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
              << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds << "s\n";
}
```

Possible output

```
finished computation at Sat Jun 16 20:42:57 2012
elapsed time: 3s
```

1. I have noticed that example uses `std::chrono::system_clock::now();` does it mean it can be used to measure only elapsed time and not the CPU time ??? And if I want to measure CPU time, what Clocks should I use ?
2. Notice that `elapsed time: 3s` is output is rounded to whole integer. Is there way to make it more granulated?

Comment: 2. Well, yeah, you used `seconds`. Use `milliseconds` and voila, more granulated! Heck, use `nanoseconds` if you want.

Comment: @chris Hm ....great advice. double elapsed_seconds = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
                             (end-start).count())/1000;

Comment: Aside: Just so that you're aware, I've encountered a compiler that took `end` to mean `std::end`. It might have been GCC 4.7.1, but I could be wrong. I know the latest version of GCC no longer does that, but it's something to watch out for if you have other compilers that will use this.

Comment: `<chrono>` is a header (and namespace), not a class. I corrected that for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Correct

   According to the standard:

   > system_clock represent[s] wall clock time from the system-wide realtime clock.

   The `<chrono>` library does not provide a mechanism for measuring CPU time, so if you want that you'll have to fall back on the old `<ctime>` library and use `std::clock()`.

   (And if you're targeting Windows you'll have to fall back on whatever platform-specific API Windows provides for getting CPU time since, as you point out, their `std::clock()` doesn't work correctly.)

   `system_clock` is more like a counterpart to `std::time()` than to `std::clock()`. (E.g., note that `system_clock` provides conversions between `system_clock::time_point`s and `time_t`.) I imagine that the lack of a clock in `<chrono>` for measuring CPU time is due to time constraints on the standard committee and the fact that that functionality is less used than the system's wall clock and real-time clocks.

   If you want CPU time but also want the benefits that `<chrono>` provides, you should implement a clock type that conforms to the Clock concept outlined in the standard and which provides CPU time, perhaps implemented internally using `std::clock()`.
2. The line that says

   > ```
   > int elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
   >                     (end-start).count();
   > ```

   is what causes the time to be rounded to an integral number of seconds. You can choose any period you'd like, or you can use a floating point representation in order to allow non-integral values:

   ```
   std::int64_t elapsed_attoseconds =
       std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::atto>>
           (end-start).count();

   double elapsed_seconds =
       std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1>>>
           (end-start).count();
   ```

   Note that in real code you should avoid using `.count()` to escape the strong typing provided by `chrono::duration` until you absolutely must.

   ```
   auto total_duration = end - start;
   auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(total_duration);
   auto milli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(total_duration - seconds);

   std::cout << seconds.count() << "s " << milli.count() << "ms\n";
   ```

Comment: Problem is `std::clock()` measures wall time on Windows, and CPU time on Linux.

Comment: @newprint Yeah, that's unfortunate. Microsoft should fix their implementation to match the standard specification.

Answer (score 4):

1) I'm fairly certain the highest resolution you can get is to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and then don't do any duration casting:

```
int elapsed_ticks = (end-start).count();
```

2) Change the argument of duration_cast to something like `nanoseconds`:

```
int elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
                             (end-start).count();
```

Comment: As an (important) note, there is a "bug" in the current `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` in VS2012 in that it is much, much lower resolution that using `QueryPerformanceCounter` and doing some math.   See: http://bit.ly/QX86s6

Comment: This bug is still present in VS2013 preview.